# Get the Location of an Error from an Error Object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, error-handling

I am trying to write some code to help me error handle compiled versions of my software. I have to run the software on several different PCs in as a compiled version to speed up uploading data to my database. I have a script that sends an email to my address when one of the PC, encounters an error rather than me having to check repeatedly.

Within the email I have the sub which the error occurred in and the error number. However I would also like the line which caused the error. I tried using `errorobject.erl` however this just gave me the value zero regardless of the position of the error. I have also tried `errorobject.source` to try and give me a more detailed location for an error, however this just returned `microsoft.visualbasic`, can this property of the error return anything in more detail?

Below is my Code:

```
 Public Sub SendErrorReport(ByVal ErrorObject As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject, ByVal Routine As String)
    'On Error GoTo Err

    Dim Recipient As String = "email1; email2"

    ' Create an Outlook application.
    Dim oApp As Outlook._Application
    oApp = New Outlook.Application()

    ' Create a new MailItem.
    Dim oMsg As Outlook._MailItem
    oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    oMsg.Subject = "Notitia software - Error report"
    oMsg.Body = "Error occurred at " & Format(Now.Hour, "00") & ":" & Format(Now.Minute, "00") & " in " & Routine & ". Error no." & Str(ErrorObject.Number) & " - " & ErrorObject.Description & vbCr & vbCr & " - Error Line: " & ErrorObject.erl
    ' TODO: Replace with a valid e-mail address.
    oMsg.To = Recipient

    ' Send
    oMsg.Send()

    ' Clean up
    oApp = Nothing
    oMsg = Nothing

    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox("Error in " & Routine & ". Error no." & Str(ErrorObject.Number) & " - " & ErrorObject.Description)

End Sub
```

So essentially I am looking for a method to increase the information about the error that this sub can send to its recipients. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject rather than System.Exception which would have that information?

Comment: Is the error being generated from VB6 or VBA code?

Comment: vb.net code which as far as I know is different from vb6 and vba. If not then i expect vb6, I am writing in visual studios 2005, in the vb.net v2 framework - does any of that help?
I will have a look at system.exception and see if that helps with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Try Catch` instead of the old VB6/VBA way of `on Error GOTO`. The Exception `StackTrace` will give you the information you need.